# How can I divide a dataset equally into two parts?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm programming on Asp.net and C#.

I have a Dataset which is populated by records from database.
On my design page, I have two Datagrids.

How can I equally divide the records inside the Dataset so they can be bound to two separate datagrids?

Comment: How many tables you have in dataset?

Comment: I have only 1 table in my dataset and i want to divide its contents into 2 parts to bind in 2 grid views. TQ

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataView on your dataset and then bind your 2 Datagrids on dataview
here a sample
http://www.dotnetperls.com/dataview

work for instance to set one dataview on rows.count/2 and the other too

Comment: you are not interesting on paging your data because if you have too many records to display , it will be usefull and user friendly.you have to use DataGridView that take a datasource : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridPaging.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

```
 var d=ds.Tables[0];// here ds is your dataset.
 int count=d.Rows.Count;
 var x=new DataTable();
 for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
 {
   var dr=d.Rows[i];   
   x.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
   d.Rows.RemoveAt(i); 
 } 
 var ret=new DataSet();
 ret.Tables.Add(x);
 ret.Tables.Add(d);
```

so now you have dataset that contain two equal datatable.

Comment: How can I reference them afterward?